# How to eliminate gap between Font Awesome Icon and paragraph in React JS?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx, font-awesome-5

I am trying to put the top side of the icon `caret-down` lined up with the bottom side of my `p`:

[image]

There is a gap between the arrow and the `p`, I don't know how to get rid of this gap.
I set `p` with `margin-bottom: 0`, but the gap of the image still remains.
My second guess was to set the icon with a negative `margin-top`, but it only works so far:

[image]

The image above shows what happens when I set the icon with `margin-top: -10px`. I am still getting a gap and this is the closest I can get the icon next to `p`, it doesn't matter how much I decrease the `margin-top`, this is the limit.

Maybe there is something about these icons that I don't know.

A sample of my code:

`JSX:`

```
<div>
   <p onClick={() => setTag('all')} className="products-select products-select-active">ALL PRODUCTS</p>
   <FontAwesomeIcon icon="caret-down" size="2x" />
</div>
```

`css:`

```
.products-select {
    width: 155px;
    height: 46px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.products-select-active {
    background-color: #3A3A3A;
    color: white;
}
```

`Icon:`

[image]

How can I fix it?

`EDIT:`

I just made my own arrow-down with css and JSX and it solved my problem.

`EDIT 2:`

@lt1 solution works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to move something around precisely, you can use the `transform` CSS property with a `translate` value. For example, here you could try

```
.products-select {
   transform: translateY(15px);
}
```

That will move the products-select down by 15px, you can adjust the value to whatever you need. (there's also translateX for a horizontal translation.)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `box-sizing: border-box` to the `products-select` class, like so:

```
.products-select {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 155px;
    height: 46px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

And then set your height. :)